# Router under 80$ with OpenVPN support

Tags: wifi, router

I need a router with OpenVPN.

So, I'm looking into a router with OpenWRT or DD-WRT support.

The router must be able to handle OpenVPN.

I need as many LAN Ports as possible. Minimum of 4.

I don't have much money so I want the cheapest one possible.

Answer (score 3):

All of [GL.iNet](http://www.gl-inet.com/products/) routers are based on OpenWRT.

You can get the [GL-AR150](http://www.gl-inet.com/ar150/) for $25 which is a pretty nice device with 16MB Flash ROM, 64MB RAM and 1 USB port.

Also, you could go for some cheap TP-LINK routers like TL-WR741N or TL-WR841N which have OpenWRT support.

Comment: Links broken, try https://www.gl-inet.com/